# Implementing Layout as a Background in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, background

In my application I have created a Relative layout containing 5 buttons and now I want to use the same layout in other layouts as a background. I am trying the code `android:background+"@layout/dashboard"` but eclipse is showing me an error. I want to show that layout as **Parent Bottom** so that I can implement a scroll view and can call all the elements except the **dashboard**. Please help me in letting me know that:

1. How can I add another layout as a background
2. How can I set that layout to alignParentBottom
3. how can I modify the scrollView so that dashboard stays static and the rest of the elements can scroll..

Code for dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Explore" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="MIC" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Msngr" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Profile" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for showdashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@layout/dashboard" >

</LinearLayout>
```

The Error that I am Getting is:

**Failed to parse file C:\Users\%username%\Documents\eclipse\CustomList\res\layout\dashboard.xml
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log**

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you would like a static view pf buttons at the bottom of the page, you can wrap those buttons in a linear layout and the put the rest inside a scroll view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:id="@+id/s_view" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- You can put your components here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- your 5 buttons here -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

you can change the size of bottom layout/scrollview by adjusting the layout weights.

If you want to use the same layout for more than one activity, then make separate linear layouts (or others if you prefer) and then you can add them to the scrollView in your activities.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);
    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.s_view);
    LayoutInflater lInflator = getLayoutInflater();
    sv.addView(lInflator.inflate(R.layout.view_component, null));

}
```

where s_view is the id of the scroll view and the component view is the target layout.

Comment: how can I add that separate layout in the scrollView? this is the thing that I want to know..

Comment: I have added more details on inflating layouts.

Answer (score 0):

What i get throught your writing you want to make `Static Buttons` But Other layout should have a `ScrollView`

So u can do this by this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:background="#ffffff" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:background="#ffffff" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1.0">
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0">
            ---Your Scroll Vieww Layout hereee-------
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F3F0EC" android:orientation="horizontal">

        ----your  5 Button Layout hereee-------
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are there so many LinearLayouts wrapped around the scroll view?

Comment: 1 st linear layout is used to make your 5 button static 
and other 2 Linearlayout is wraaped it will be useful in your scrolling i have done in my way  please u try ? is it useful for u  ?

Comment: @raghavchopra sir, thanks for your code but I want to know that how can I implement the RelativeLayout data in the LinearLayout as a background.. I dont want to write the code again and again..